# "Visible" property on XPages edit boxes based on checkbox selection(s)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am new to XPages, and I have a Check Box Group ('checkBoxGroup1') as one of my design elements that contains three choices ("CBChoice1", "CBChoice1", "CBChoice1").  Underneath that Check Box Group, I have three edit box fields which correspond to the three checkbox choices.  Each time one of the checkbox choices is chosen, I want the corresponding edit box to become visible.

Whenever one of the checkboxes is chosen, I have it partially refreshing the panel that the edit boxes are in, but I cannot figure out the code in each of the edit box's visible property.  I started with

```
getComponent('checkBoxGroup1').getValue() == "CBChoice1"
```

which kind of works, but isn't *the* answer.  I also tried

```
var valueArray = getComponent('checkBoxGroup1').getSelectedValues();
valueArray[0] == "CBChoice1";
```

which seems more on target, but I was getting the following browser error:

Error 500  HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

I notice that in the computed code for the visibility property, it is SSJS.  I feel like I am close, but have been banging my head for too long.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better method might be to bind the checkbox group to either a document data source or a scope variable.

Then, your visible property might look something like:

```
@Contains(myDoc.getItemValueArray("checkBoxFieldName"),"CBChoice1");
```

or

```
@Contains(viewScope.get("checkBoxScopeVar"),"CBChoice1");
```